# How to launch a dialog box with fill-in-fields in a Powerpoint 2010/2013 document?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vba, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I would like to set a PPT presentation which launches a dialog box at the opening of the document where I could directly fill in some fields with information (such as the name of my client, the name of the project, etc.). These informations would automatically appear on some slides of my presentation within specific text boxes.

This would be easy if I could use the macro recorder tool - just like in Excel, Word or Powerpoint 2007, but this feature has been removed since the 2010 version. I could easily record a macro which starts at the opening and asks the user to fill in the dialog box - or directly, the textboxes on the required slides - but this is not possible anymore.

Thus, I have to proceed using VBA, but I don't know anything about this code. That's why I would like to find the piece of code which allows me to implement this option in my document. Any ideas?

I'm working on PPT 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an inputbox to get the value (string) and then navigate to the slides/shapes and set the value to the inputbox string:

```
Sub test()
Dim x As String

x = InputBox("What is your name?", Name)
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange = x

End Sub
```

It's not as intuitive as excel, I'd start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861525%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Or, if you're brave, try a [userform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff744139%28v=office.14%29.aspx)